# REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG from VB.NET to C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, com

Here's my problem.

I have written a class in VB.NET under Visual Studio 2015 (**MyLibrary**).
I compile it as a DLL with *'Make assembly COM-Visible'* checked, so it generates a .tlb file in addition to the DLL file.

Then I try to instanciate this class in C++ code, under Visual Studio 2013, using the COM mechanism.
For that, I make the .tlh file generated by :

```
#import "MyLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

Then I do :

```
// Initialize COM.
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

// Create the interface pointer.
cMyLibraryPtr l_pclMyLibrary(__uuidof(MyLibrary));

// Use it
l_pclMyLibrary->DoThings();
```

When I do it from the computer where both versions of Visual Studio are installed, it works well, either in debug or release mode.
But when I launch it from another computer where I "installed" my software, I get the **REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG** when the constructor of my class calls "**CreateInstance**".

I've checked or tried those things to make it work :

1. Everythings is compiled in x86 (VB.NET and C++) and I'm on two 32bits targets
2. I tried to register my library by calling "regasm.exe MyLibrary.dll". I checked in regedit that the registration worked.

I don't know what I can do more... So any help would be welcome!

Thanks
Alex.

Comment: Show the **exact** regasm command you used including all specified options.

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck using:

```
regasm /tlb /codebase MyLibrary.dll
```

Note the /tlb and /codebase parameters...

I'd also want to make sure you run it from an elevated command line that has administrator privileges.

In addition, you need to be sure that the version of regasm.exe that you are using is

1) the same version of .NET that you build your DLL
2) In your case, that it is the 32-bit version of regasm.exe and not the 64-bit version

The other thing, is if you are going to distribute these in the same install directory, you could use Isolated COM so that registration is not even necessary.